# Clarification of RSA Key Exchange (TLS 1.2) and AES for On-Going Message Excahnge

Tags: tls, authentication, aes, rsa

I'm trying to understand the full flow of key exchanges for secure communications.

As a potentially incorrect premise, I am under the impression that RSA is a good asymmetric technique for establishing a secure connection through which a subsequent symmetric key exchange can occur and that the AES cipher block is a better method for high volume message exchanges because it's faster than RSA encryption. Meaning, RSA asymmetric is good for an exchange of a small message such as a shared [session] secret key.

With that said, I understand the flow between Alice and Bob as follows:

1. Alice sends ClientHello to Bob (Server)
2. Bob responds with Acknowledgement
3. Alice responds with a Public Key (RSA's public half)
4. And (potentially?) a Message Digest which consists of a one-way hash
   (such as sha()) of Alice's public key that was encrypted by Alice's
   Private Key
5. Bob receives Alice's public key, uses it to decrypt the one way
   hash, uses the same hashing function (sha()) to hash the public key
   and then compares the decrypted one-way hash from Alice and the
   one-way hash he generated
6. If it matches, he believes the connection and sends his own public
   key to Alice
7. Along with that Public key, he sends a one-way hash of his key
   (maybe concatenated with Alice's public key?) with which Alice can
   repeat the process of decrypting using Bob's public key and then
   comparing the one-way hash of his key (or maybe of his key combined
   with Alice's public key?)
8. Once the two parties can see that there is a secure connection
   (because of each having a hash match), they can a) store their
   respective public keys and b) make an exchange of a secret symmetric
   session key that would then follow AES for more high volume message
   exchanges

Is this correct? Is it more common for simply the RSA key exchange to be done? is this the correct method for key exchange? Is this an accurate representation of TLS1.2? Have I invented any steps?

I know this is a lot of questions with potentially more than one area I've misunderstood the processes. I appreciate the clarification and help!